# optional argument with ternary operator

Tags: python, arguments, option-type, ternary-operator

I have a function `f` that may take a variable number of arguments, like this:

```
f = f_5_args if five else f_4_args
```

To call `f`, I'm currently doing this:

```
if five:
  result = f(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)
else:
  result = f(x1, x2, x3, x4)
```

Is there a nicer way to call `f`, that would also use a ternary operator or something similar? In other languages like Lua, I would be able to do something like:

```
result = f(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 if five else None)
```

But I can't find something equivalent in python.

EDIT: of course I could do:

```
result = f(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) if five else f(x1, x2, x3, x4)
```

but in my situation the x_i are some relatively long expressions, so I would prefere not to write them twice. I could store them in some variables and do this, but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: What are `f_5_args` and `f_4_args`?

Comment: They are 2 functions that take respectively (and strictly) 5 and 4 arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the list of arguments, you could make it more concise by using slicing:

```
args = [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]
result = f(*args) if five else f(*args[:4])
```

But it would probably be easier to use a function that accepts an arbitrary number of positional arguments:

```
def f45(*args):
    if len(args) == 5:
         # do something
    elif len(args) == 4:
         # do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
result = f(*(filter(None, (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 if five else None))))
```

Note that this solution eliminates all the False and zero values together with `None`s, so use it if it suits your use case.

Comment: What if some argument `x` has a falsy value?

Comment: Yes, my solution eliminates all the False and zero values together with `None`s.

Comment: This is obviously not a pythonic way to pass paramters to a function

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
fargs = [x1, x2, x3, x4]
if five:
    fargs.append(x5)
    result = f_5_args(*fargs)
else:
    result = f_4_args(*fargs)
```

That avoids having to write out all your function arguments twice.